# Why is the table drawn over footer instead of being moved to the next page?

Tags: tables, floats, page-breaking, ltablex, placeins

On the second page the table is drawn over the footer instead of being moved to the next page.

But the first table **does** get moved to the second page instead of being drawn right after `\lipsum[1-2]`, where there is not enough space.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{placeins}

\newcommand{\maketable}[1]{
    \FloatBarrier
    \begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|}
    \hline
    #1\\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    \FloatBarrier
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\maketable{
    \lipsum[1]
}

\maketable{
    \lipsum[1-2]
}

\end{document}
```

---

What I tried:

- **Removing `\FloatBarrier`.**
  Tables fly all over the place. Sometimes tables jump above the text that should go before them. Sometimes I get gigantic vertical gaps between tables for no apparent reason.
- **Removing `\begin{table} ... \end{table}`.** Tables get transferred to the next page, but the top `hhline` is left behind.
- **Using `tabularx` instead of `ltablex`.** The second table does get moved to the next page, but the first table is placed in the middle of the page, instead of at the top. Using `\begin{table}[ht]` instead of `\begin{table}[h]` does not help (in log it says [h] is changed to [ht] automatically anyway). Seems like using `longtable` inside a float is a bad idea (which is to be expected, I guess). Still, why does the first table get placed in the middle of the page when using regular `tabularx`?
- **Tried using both TexLive and MikTex, they both produced identical pdf. [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_I-IfjALTdy5CWTTOhKhZkKqq2Z-vplO/view?usp=sharing)**

---

Apparently, using `\begin{table}[H]` (requires `\usepackage{float}`) fixes the issue somehow.

I have no idea why, and I am worried that using [H] might create a lot of other problems later, but so far I haven't noticed any.

Here is how it looks with [H]: **[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z6uL6iaJMxuu26KsUan562I44eczTuha/view?usp=sharing)**

Comment: I cant reproduce your problem (tested with recent MikTeX). See if updating of your LaTeX installation will help.

Comment: I used texlive. Will try with MikTex and report the result.

Comment: @Zarko I installed last version of MikTex and it produced identical pdf file. I will upload the pdf and link it in the question.

Comment: My test file: `\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{placeins}
\newcommand{\maketable}[1]{\FloatBarrier
    \begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|}\hline #1\\ \hline\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    \FloatBarrier
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\maketable{\lipsum[1]}

\maketable{\lipsum[1-2]}
\end{document}`. With it the both tables are on the second page. In test I use MikTeX, recent version.

Comment: @Zarko both tables being on the second page **is** the issue. Does your file look like **[this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_I-IfjALTdy5CWTTOhKhZkKqq2Z-vplO/view?usp=sharing)**? The second table is drawn over the page number.

Comment: you are right. I overlooked this. If I remove `\FloatBarrier` before and after `table` float, table start to float -- second table is moved to third page. See if the following is acceptable: `\usepackage{float} 
\newcommand{\maketable}[1]{%
\begin{table}[H] 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|}\hline #1\\ \hline\end{tabularx} 
\end{table} }`

Comment: Removing \FloatBarrier allows the tables to jump above text, which was meant to be before the table. It is not evident in this example, but without using some other solution to resolve this issue, removing \FloatBarrier is not an acceptable solution. I did write about using H in the end of the question, it works regardless of \FloatBarrier. The problem is that [H] is knows to cause problems of it's own and is generally not recommended AFAIK. And I would like to know why does the table get messed up like that in the first place.

Comment: Because you enclose an environment into command? Background of your approach is unknown, but to me seems that use of `tcolorbox` will do this better. See, if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521709/how-can-i-kept-caption-figure-pie-in-tcolorbox gives an idea for other possibility to design framed text box.

Comment: I tried this without using a command and the second table indeed jumped to the next page. Still, the first table was not placed at the top of the first page, but instead skipped a decent chunk of vertical space for no reason. This is similar to when I tried using `tabularx` instead of `ltablex` (inside a command). Will check out the link you provided, thanks.

Comment: Your command is adding spaces you probably don't want, which can only confuse things.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use a command like this that puts float barriers on both sides of a float. If you don't want it to float, don't use a float. This is very like using `H` or using a `tabular` without `table` or whatever. All **will** cause problems you probably don't expect. Occasionally, these kinds of things are useful, but if you use them routinely, you'll get lots of strange spacing issues because what else is LaTeX supposed to do? You've given it one option and it's a bad one.

Comment: When table without tabular is moved to the next page, the top `hline` if left behind. Kind of a deal-breaker.