# How to keep a figure caption with tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

[image]
How can I keep a caption  figure inside a tcolorbox?
I want to put the pie in a tcb but when I delete `\begin{figure}[h]` and `\end{figure}`, the caption is removed. Any solutions? Thanks.

Illustration:

```
 \begin{figure}[h]
 \centering 
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \pie [polar]{10/Excellentes, 20/Bonnes, 30/Moyennes, 40/Mauvaises}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{ Présentation  }
 \label{fig: Question}
 \end{figure}

 \\

 \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white]

 \centering 
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \pie [polar]{10/Excellentes, 20/Bonnes, 30/Moyennes, 40/Mauvaises}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{ Présentation  ghjghjghjg }
 \label{fig: Qp}
 \end{tcolorbox}
```

Answer (score 4):

Welcome! `tcolorbox` allows you to have floats such as figures in (or, more precisely, as) `tcolorbox`es. You need to define a `tcolorbox` for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[h]
 \centering 
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \pie [polar]{10/Excellentes, 20/Bonnes, 30/Moyennes, 40/Mauvaises}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{ Pr\'esentation  }
 \label{fig: Question}
 \end{figure}

% define a tcolorbox version of figures, see p. 115 of the manual
\newtcolorbox[blend into=figures]{myfigure}[2][]{float=htb,capture=hbox,
title={#2},every float=\centering,#1}


\begin{myfigure}[label={fig:Qp},% <- label goes here
    colback=white]{Another pr\'esentation.}% <- caption goes here
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \pie [polar]{10/Excellentes, 20/Bonnes, 30/Moyennes, 40/Mauvaises}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{myfigure}

As shown in figure~\ref{fig:Qp}, one can have floats in (or, more precisely, as)
\verb|tcolorbox|es.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, please consider for the future to provide us with complete documents that start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`, are minimal and can be compiled.